# React Native - TextInput onLayout event reports undefined height and width

Tags: react-native

I am trying to find the height and width of a TextInput so that I can size it properly in my app but the onLayout event fired for TextInput has an `undefined` height and width. Below is an Expo Snack reproducing the problem

https://snack.expo.io/SJXTwtxl-

The code is pretty simple:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  onLayout = (e) => {
    Alert.alert('TextInput Layout', 'Height: ' + e.height + ', Width: ' + e.width)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
        placeholder={'Type a message'}
        value={'Hello there'}
        multiline={true}
        style={styles.textInput}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        enablesReturnKeyAutomatically={true}
        onLayout={this.onLayout}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I was expecting the height and width to be some positive values but they are reported as `undefined`. Is that expected?

Comment: I think the correct reference to width+height is through `e.nativeEvent.layout`

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out and came back to the question to report back my finding. Was stumped by the documentation for the method that says >Invoked on mount and layout changes with {x, y, width, height}.